# Stroke width for outlook email

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a stroke width for emails outside of outlook, but I can't make it thicker for outlook.  Does anyone know how I can fix this code so that a thick border appears for outlook emails?  Thank you!

```
<div>
<!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
href="mailto" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:400px;" arcsize="100%" 
strokecolor="#ec632e"stroke-width="5px" fillcolor="#ffffff">
<w:anchorlock/>
<center style="color:#ec632e;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">
Click here to schedule a meeting</center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
<a href="mailto"
style="background-color:#ffffff;border:4px solid #ec632e;
border-radius:40px;color:#ec632e;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;width:400px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">
Click here to schedule a meeting</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought outlook didn't support borders on `<a>`.. but I assume it does now. You do see the 1px border?

Comment: Yes it's default to 1px.  the stroke-width I wrote above didn't work for outlook, it's still 1px.